# Axios get Request not receiving data

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, axios

I am trying to download the content of my s3 bucket, and when I hit the API endpoint the data shows in my Intellij console, but in my postman and browser console I simply get an empty object.

Is there a certain why I am supposed to receive this in an Axios request?

Axios -

```
downloadLocations() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/targetLocation/downloadSearchData")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)

        // We will need to retrieve the data into a downloadable blob
        // const  content = new Blob([JSON.stringify(???)],{ type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })
        // const fileName = `test.txt`
        // saveAs(content, fileName)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Service -

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadSearchData() throws IOException {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    var s3Object = s3client.getObject("downloadable-cases", "7863784198_2021-08-16T13_30_06.690Z.json");
    var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (var in = s3Object.getObjectContent()) {
        in.transferTo(out);
    }
    System.out.println(out);
    return out;
}
```

Controller -

```
@GetMapping(value = "downloadSearchData")
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadSearchData() throws IOException {
    return targetLocationService.downloadSearchData();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I changed the Service and Controller return value to String and it now works perfectly

```
public String downloadSearchData() throws IOException {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.GovCloud)
            .build();

    var s3Object = s3client.getObject("downloadable-cases", "7863784198_2021-08-16T13_30_06.690Z.json");
    var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (var in = s3Object.getObjectContent()) {
        in.transferTo(out);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```